# Pandas concat from excel tables with missing data

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to concatenate a number of tables that I have read from excel and pivoted (stacked) using pandas. The code below works perfectly except the final dataframe (GRL) is missing the last two columns. Those columns correspond to columns in the input excel file that have several empty cells as the first entries. I have tried using concat on subsets of the data (and test data) and it seems to work, but not for the whole data set. It seems that the pd.concat is not taking a union on the datetime index where the column starts with missing data.

Can anyone spot a glaring mistake here? Thanks.

```
path = 'C:\\dr\\'
WQ_file = 'File.xlsx'

xl = pd.ExcelFile(path + WQ_file)
sheet_names = xl.sheet_names

GRL = pd.read_excel(path + WQ_file, sheetname = sheet_names[0], parse_cols = 15, index_col = 0, na_values = ['', 'na'])
GRL = GRL.stack(dropna=False).reorder_levels([1,0]).sortlevel(0)
GRL.name = sheet_names[0]

for n in sheet_names[1:-1]:
    df1 = pd.read_excel(path + WQ_file, sheetname = n, parse_cols = 15, index_col = 0, na_values = ['', 'na'])
    df1 = df1.stack(dropna=False).reorder_levels([1,0]).sortlevel(0)
    df1.name = n
    GRL = pd.concat([GRL, df1], axis = 1)
GRL.columns.name = 'Locations'
GRL
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually works. So there is no problem. Thanks